# Cast unknown-int? element of HashMap to double

Tags: java, casting, int, double

I have `HashMap<String,?>` , where ? can be String, int or double ..
Normally the problem is that you cant cast int to double but there is workaround..

Even harder is how to cast '?' to double, where the hash element could be int or double ?

```
 double val = (double) hash.get("num")
```

this fails if the hash-value is 'int'.
Is the only way to cast it like a String and then parse it ?

---

```
 double val = ((Number) hash.get("num")).doubleValue()
```

Comment: how do i do that ? hash.get('num'),getClass()??

Comment: Better yet, choose a class for the key.